# FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION: Enter the same currency as the parent Order.: Currency ISO Code: [CurrencyIsoCode]

Tags: apex, quote, order

I have enabled multi currency in my org and while converting quote to Order the Order is getting created without Order line items, even though Quote had line items.

May I know why I might be getting this error?

The debug logs says as below

```
09:00:30.610 (7189277217)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|UpdateOBOrderLineItem on OrderItem trigger event BeforeInsert|__sfdc_trigger/UpdateOBOrderLineItem
09:00:30.610 (7207184135)|DML_END|[92]
09:00:30.610 (7207367888)|EXCEPTION_THROWN|[92]|System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, Enter the same currency as the parent Order.: Currency ISO Code: [CurrencyIsoCode]
09:00:30.610 (7209218918)|DML_BEGIN|[20]|Op:Update|Type:SBQQ__Quote__c|Rows:1
09:00:31.262 (7262024299)|CUMULATIVE_LIMIT_USAGE
```

But it is not saying which class or method, or which automation is causing this issue.

Can someone please help me with this. Thanks in advance.